# Kazhdan-Lusztig Conjecture over non-algebraically closed field

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, kazhdan-lusztig, category-o

Let $G$ be a split connected semi-simple (or reductive) algebraic group over a (non-archimedean) field $k$ of characteristic zero. Denote by $\mathfrak{g}=\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ the semi-simple (or reductive) Lie algebra over $k$ associated to $G$ with Weyl group $W$.

As far I understood the material correct the Kazhdan–Lusztig polynomials $P_{x,w}$ as well as the Verma module $M_w$ resp. the simple highest weight module $L_w$ of highest weight $-w(\rho)-\rho$ are well-defined for $x,w \in W$ and any such field $k$.

Hence I was wondering whether the Kazhdan-Lusztig conjecture holds in general. But so far the literature I found always refers to $k$ being algebraically closed. Does something go wrong for $k$ being non algebraically closed?

Comment: How are you phrasing the KL conjecture in this case? Is it clear that the simple modules you want to talk about even exist?

Comment: Do you want your highest weights to be $-w\rho + \rho$, rather than $-w\rho - \rho$?

Comment: It may also be relevant to notice that the character of an algebraic representation is an algebraic object; it is insensitive to base change, so that you may as well work over the algebraic closure of your field when computing it.  Similarly, when you are already working over a splitting field, the Weyl group remains the same after base change to an algebraic closure.

Comment: As we assume that $G$ is split and we are in characteristic zero, it follows that there is a cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ which is split. Hence we can proceed as in Humphreys "Representation of Semisimple Lie algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}"$, especially chapter 1 where $M_w$ and $L_w$ are defined. I would phrase the KL conjecture as usual: $ch(L_w)=\sum_{x\leq w} (-1)^{l(w)-l(x)}P_{x,w}(1)ch(M_x)$.

Comment: @LSpice  No $-w(\rho)-\rho=w \cdot (-2\rho)$ is right. Look for example at page 159 in Humphries Book I mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure that when we construct (the simple module) $L_w$ from (the Verma module) $M_w$, we never need to talk about decomposition into eigenspaces, which might not exist when the field is not algebraically closed? Not an expert in this at all, but my sense is a lot of the basics of rep. theory of semisimple Lie algebras breaks down without the algebraically closed assumption.

Comment: @LSpice So also Vogans identity $P_{x,w}=\sum_i q^i \dim(Ext_{\mathcal{O}}^{l(w)-l(x)-2i}(M_x,L_w))$ remains the same under base change?

Comment: The only assumption that Humphreys make in the beginning is that the eigenvalues of $\mathrm{ad}(h)$ are in $k$ for every $h \in \mathfrak{h}$ i.e. $\mathfrak{h}$ is split. Which as I said is fulfilled. Only for convenience he assume to work over $\mathbb{C}$. Looking in the proof of theorem 1.2 in Humphreys book I see nothing more needed. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, Humphreys writes $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathcal O}$ for Ext in the category of $\mathfrak g$-modules.  Since this, too, is insensitive to base change, the [identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378912/kazhdan-lusztig-conjecture-over-non-algebraically-closed-field#comment961677_378912) you quote should be.  (The Hecke algebra as Humphreys defines it does not depend on the base field in the first place.)  I am avoiding @SamHopkins's question about whether the modules are defined over $k$, although I agree with you that I see no obstruction.

Comment: I just notice that one has to distinguish between $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}}$ and $\mathrm{Ext}_{U(\mathfrak{g})}$, as category $\mathcal{O}$ is not closed under extensions (e.g exercise 3.1 in Humphreys book).